# Is it OK to use an Effect/Result transition word after hypotheses/assumptions?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, conditionals, transitions

> The natural response to being asked about stimuli presented before might be to think about the first previous stimulus. Therefore responding to a 2-back task might require response inhibition.

The conclusion I made is valid if we take the previous sentence as true, however the first sentence is just an idea/hypothesis about what might be true. Is it OK to use an effect/result transition word(e.g. therefore, consequently, hence) here or should you explicitly state something like "If we take the the assumptions in the previous sentence as true then...".

Comment: It is quite difficult to respond to a question about a sentence that is incomplete. What is supposed to be true? There is a basic form for conditionals in an English sentence. "If A, then B." More elaborate forms are available, particulary when the antecedent or consequence is complex. For example, you might start a paragraph with "If the hypothesis in the preceding paragraph is true, then X. Therefore Y, Consequently, Z. The whole chain of reasoning in the paragraph would be understood to be contingent on the truth of the hypothesis articulated in the preceding paragraph. Is that your query?

Comment: For some reason, the sentence in the query requires scrolling to be seen completely. It would be easier to read with some line feeds inserted.

Comment: I think that by the word "concussion" you meant "conclusion". Your post has some jargon in it that is unfamiliar: "2-back task". Is that a reference to a stimulus? It might be better to combine the two sentences with a comma and the word "so" in place of  "therefore".  Maybe "The natural response to being asked about stimuli that have been presented might be to think about the immediately preceding stimulus, so getting a response about the second-last stimulus might require response inhibition."